# Dependence between parameters in Bayesian multilevel regression

Tags: regression, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian

I am working on a Bayesian multilevel regression model, which is specified as

$$
y_{ij}=x_{ij}'\beta+\delta_j+\varepsilon_{ij}\\
\delta_j=\gamma_{\operatorname{region}(j)}+\eta_j
$$
where $i$ indexes county, $j$ indexes state and the slightly awkward notation $\operatorname{region}(j)$ denotes the region of state $j$ (of which there are four). Thus, there are four $\gamma$ parameters. We can assume independence and normality of the errors. The model can also be written as
$$
y_{ij}=\begin{pmatrix} x_{ij}' & e_{\operatorname{region}(j)}'\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\beta \\\gamma\end{pmatrix}+\eta_j+\varepsilon_{ij}\\
=z_{ij}'\theta+\nu_{ij}.
$$
By normality and independence, this means that we have that $y\sim N(Z\theta, \Sigma_y)$ with some $\Sigma_y$ which only depends on the variances of the two error terms.

As a prior distribution, I assume that $\theta\mid\sigma_\beta, \sigma_\gamma\sim N(0, \Sigma_\theta)$ where
$$
\Sigma_\theta=\begin{pmatrix}\sigma^2_\beta I_p & 0 \\ 0 & \sigma^2_\gamma I_4\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
where $p$ is the dimension of $\beta$.

Now, what I am interested in is the conditional posterior of $\theta$, where I postulate uniform priors for $\sigma_\beta$ and $\sigma_\gamma$. Thus,
$$
p(\theta\mid Y, Z, \Sigma_y, \sigma_\beta, \sigma_\gamma)\propto p(Y\mid Z, \theta, \Sigma_y)p(\theta\mid\sigma_\beta, \sigma_\gamma).
$$
If we take the log to simplify the notation a little bit, this gives
$$
\log p(\theta\mid Y, Z, \Sigma_y, \sigma_\beta, \sigma_\gamma) \propto \frac{-1}{2} (y-Z\theta)'\Sigma_y^{-1}(y-Z\theta)-\frac{1}{2} \theta' \Sigma_\theta^{-1}\theta\\
\propto -\frac{1}{2}(\theta-\bar{\theta})'\bar{\Sigma}_\theta^{-1}(\theta-\bar{\theta})
$$
where
$$
\bar{\theta}=\bar{\Sigma}_\theta Z'\Sigma_y^{-1}y\\
\bar{\Sigma}_\theta=\left(Z'\Sigma_y^{-1}Z+\Sigma_\theta^{-1}\right)^{-1}.
$$
Hence, the conditional posterior is $N(\bar{\theta}, \bar{\Sigma}_\theta)$.

**Now to my question:** I find that in my simulation, the $\gamma$ values in each step in the MCMC run are almost exactly parallel. Is this to be expected? If so, what is the explanation? Here is a picture of $50$ iterations using a simulated data set with true values $10$, $3$, $-3$ and $10$. They all lie where they should, but it's the dependence I'm wondering about.

[image]

Comment: Do you mind sharing some code to reproduce?